# Why won't the state change in a unit test for an AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-runner

I'm using Angular-ui Router not $routeProvider. My controller is:

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', [
  '$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', 'userService', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, userService) {
    $scope.init = function() {
      $rootScope.pageTitle = 'Login';
      $scope.auth = {};
      return $scope.errors = null;
    };
    $scope.login = function() {
      return userService.login($scope.auth).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.authenticated === true) {
          console.log("Movin states!");
          return $state.go('dashboard');
        } else {
          return $scope.errors = {
            message: 'Invalid credentials',
            type: 'error'
          };
        }
      });
    };
    return $scope.init();
  }
]);
```

In my test, I'm doing:

```
it('should properly authenticate a user', function() {
  $scope.init();
  $scope.auth = {
    username: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'mypassword'
  };
  $scope.login();
  deferred.resolve({
    authenticated: true
  });
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect($state.current.name).toEqual('dashboard');
});
```

However, the `$state.current.name` stays as `''`. Why won't it update?

Comment: are you sure you don't have a failing promise there? `userService.login($scope.auth)` looks like it makes an http call, but I don't see any `$httpBackend` mock.

Comment: Where does `deferred` come from ?

Comment: `deferred = $q.defer()`

Comment: can you extend your test up to describe and how you inject the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed all things in your controller try below things in structured format for a login :

```
  var app = angular.module('app', [...Define dependencies here..]);

    //Contant For Login Process

       app.constant(

                'AUTH_EVENTS', {
                   loginSuccess: 'auth-login-success',
                   loginFailed: 'auth-login-failed',
                   logoutSuccess: 'auth-logout-success',
                   sessionTimeout: 'auth-session-timeout',
                   notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
                   notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
                }
       )

//Service to maintain User Session after Login

        .service('Session', function () {

            this.setSession = function(sessionId, userId, userRole){
                this.id = sessionId;
                this.userId = userId;
                this.userRole = userRole;    
            };
            this.create = function (sessionId, userId, userRole) {

              localStorage.setItem("sessionId" , sessionId);
              localStorage.setItem("userId" , userId);
              localStorage.setItem("userRole" , userRole);
              this.setSession(sessionId, userId, userRole);

            };
            this.destroy = function () {
              localStorage.clear();
              this.id = null;
              this.userId = null;
              this.userRole = null;
            };
            return this;

            }
    )

//Auth Service Factory for login logic

       .factory('AuthService', function ($http, Session) {

               return {
                 login: function (credentials) {
                   return $http
                     .post('LOGIN_API_URL_HERE', credentials)
                     .then(function (res) {
                       Session.create('1', '1', 'Employee');
                     });

                 },
                 isAuthenticated: function () {
                   return !!Session.userId;
                 },
                 isAuthorized: function (authorizedRoles) {
                   if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
                     authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
                   }
                   return (this.isAuthenticated() && authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
                 }
               };
       })


//Controller 

     .controller('loginController', ['$scope','$location', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 'AuthService', function($scope, $location, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService){

                if (AuthService.isAuthenticated() === false) {

                    $scope.page_heading = "App";
                    $scope.credentials = {
                        username: '',
                        password: ''
                    };
                    $scope.login = function (credentials) {

                     if(credentials.username != "" && credentials.password != ""){

                        AuthService.login(credentials).then(function () {
                            $scope.login_message = AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess;
                             // Path After login        
                             $location.path("/");
                              }, function () {
                            $scope.login_message = AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed;

                              });

                     }else{
                        $scope.login_message =  credentials.username == "" ? 'Username Required' :  $scope.login_message;
                        $scope.login_message =  credentials.password == "" ? 'Password Required' :  $scope.login_message;
                        $scope.login_message =  credentials.username == "" && credentials.password == "" ? 'Username & Password Required' : $scope.login_message;
                     }
                    };
                }else{
                               // Path After login
                    $location.path("/");
                }
            }]);
```

Now after login you can check anywhere for session like this

```
if (localStorage.getItem('sessionId') != "")
       // Check for session in localstorage used in case of  single time login
    Session.setSession(localStorage.getItem('sessionId'),localStorage.getItem('userId'), localStorage.getItem('userRole'));

if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()){

   // Redirect to Dashboard
}else{

  //Redirect to Login
}
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GvKmEF6NAee02J8Ru3UF?p=preview):

```
 beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, userService,$q,$state) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('LoginController', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $rootScope:$rootScope,
      userService:userService,
      $state:$state
    });

    _userService = userService;
    _$q = $q;
    _$state = $state;

  }));

  it('should properly authenticate a user', function() {
   // $scope.init();
   // $scope.auth = {
  //    username: 'test@test.com',
  //    password: 'mypassword'
  //  };

    //Set up
    var deferred = _$q.defer();
    spyOn(_userService,"login").and.callFake(function(){//fake the real implementation 
      //we don't need parameters in our fake function.
      //we only care about our return value.   
         return deferred.promise;
    }); 
    spyOn(_$state,"go"); //mock the $state.go method so that we can verify whether it was called.

    $scope.login();
    deferred.resolve({
      authenticated: true
    });

    $scope.$digest();
    expect(_$state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dashboard');//verify
  });
```

Some points to note:

- Unit tests should be **isolated** from each other and from **other real implementations**. Therefore when you set up a test, the test should not rely on `$scope.init();` to set up your test. This implementation may change which may introduce failure to your test inadvertently.
- Instead of testing for `$state.current.name`, you should test whether `$state.go` was called with correct parameters as it's more direct.

Comment: spyOn(_$state,"go"); //mock the $state.go method so that we can verify whether it was called.It is the key :) thank you